# Why i do not need to set onload event to run setInterval() method in the script tag?

Tags: javascript

Hello I am new in Javascript i want to know that this code is changing image every four seconds and it is working very well but i did not give onload event here to run setInterval() method but still setInterval() got called how? who called setInterval() method?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>       
    <title>sliding image</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="img1" src=""alt="" width="1200px">
    <script>
       let images = [
           "C:\\Users\\SUDARSHAN\\Desktop\\html_UI\\images\\1200px-Heart_corazon.svg.png",
           "C:\\Users\\SUDARSHAN\\Desktop\\html_UI\\images\\alex-haney-AGqzy-Uj3s4-unsplash.jpg",
            "C:\\Users\\SUDARSHAN\\Desktop\\html_UI\\images\\mitchell-luo-jz4ca36oJ_M-unsplash.jpg"
        ];
        let i = 0;
        
        function image()
        {  
              let img2=document.getElementById("img1");
              i = (i + 1) % images.length;
              img2.src = images[i];
        }
       window.setInterval(image,4000);
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `window.setInterval(image,4000);` there's your call - what exactly are you unclear about? How the `<script>` HTML tag works?

Comment: who are calling setInterval() because  i did not give onload event here who called setInterval()?

Comment: You have an inline script, it gets executed automatically: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#notes *"[...] inline scripts, are fetched and executed immediately, before the browser continues to parse the page."*

Comment: if script tag is executed automatically then why do we need to use onload event?

Answer (score 0):

Code in `<script>` elements is ran automatically when the script tag is received. To wait until the page finishes loading, you do `<script defer>`.

For example,

```html
<script>
  console.log("Hello World!")
</script>
```

This would print `Hello World!` to the console immediately when the `<script>` tag is received.

```html
<script defer>
  console.log("Hello World!")
</script>
```

This would print `Hello World!` to the console after the page finishes loading.

Comment: are you sure about that? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer *"This attribute must not be used if the `src` attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect."*